# Copy specific cells from range into new worksheet range

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm trying to build a VBA macro which reads cells from two different tables and populates a new table in a different worksheet. I've been able to copy entire rows and move to a new worksheet, but I only want specific cells for this new macro and I'm having a hard time figure this out.

I have two tables on a Sheet called '**Estimate**'

- *Materials* Table is A9:G100
- *Labour* Table is I9:M100

And I need to copy data into a Sheet called '**BOM**'

- Bill of Materials Table is A9:C100

What I want to do is:

```
First Loop:
    if A9-A100 <> ""
     Copy A, C, G
     Paste to Worksheet "BOM" into Columns A9-100:C9-100
End first loop

Second Loop:
    if I9-I00 <> ""
     Copy I, K, M
     Paste to Worksheet "BOM" AFTER the last row in the first loop
End second loop
```

This is the code I've gotten to, but have gone through multiple different iterations so forgive me if it's a bit of a mess.

```
' BOM Generation
Sub BuildBOM()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Dim sheet_names As Variant

    ' Assign the source of the estimate I want to copy
    Set SourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Estimate")
    Set TargetSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM")
    
    ' Which Cells do I want to copy from the Estimte
    cls = Array("A", "C", "G", "I", "K", "M")
    
    ' Which Cells do I want to copy into the BOM
    dls = Array("A", "B", "C")
    
    ' What row do I start the paste on
    j = 9
    
    ' Clear the previous BOM items before creating/refreshing
    TargetSht.Rows(j & ":" & TargetSht.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    
    ' Switch to the BOM sheet
    TargetSht.Activate

    ' First loop of the Materials table
    For Each c In SourceSht.Range("A9:A100")
    
        ' Check if there's content in A column, starting the desired row
        If c <> "" Then
            'SourceSht.Rows(c.Row).Copy
            SourceSht.Range("A:A").Copy
            TargetSht.Range("A:A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Hopefully this is enough, but please do let me know if I'm missing anything to help understand the end result I'm looking for.

Here's a few visuals if it helps
[image: Materials Table]
[image: Labour Table]
[image: Final BOM Table]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some variables that are not declared in your `Sub`, it is a good practice to always declare all your variables explicitly with their type. Insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you enforce that.

Since your goal involves a lot of reading and transferring of values from cell to cell. it is recommended to process all these values in an array vs processing from the cell directly. (Reading/writing into/from cells is a very expensive process so the less the better)

Try below code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BuildBOM()
    ' Assign the source of the estimate I want to copy
    Dim SourceSht As Worksheet
    Set SourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Estimate")
    
    Dim sourceCols() As String
    ' Which Cells do I want to copy from the Estimte
    sourceCols = Split("A,C,G,I,K,M", ",")
       
    'Declare array to hold the source columns' value
    Dim dataCheck As Variant
    Dim dataFirstCol As Variant
    Dim dataSecondCol As Variant
    
    'Array to hold the output value to insert into BOM
    Dim dataOutput As Variant
    ReDim dataOutput(1 To 3, 1 To 200) As Variant
    Dim outputIndex As Long
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(sourceCols) Step 3
        dataCheck = SourceSht.Range(Replace("!9:!100", "!", sourceCols(i))).Value
        dataFirstCol = SourceSht.Range(Replace("!9:!100", "!", sourceCols(i + 1))).Value
        dataSecondCol = SourceSht.Range(Replace("!9:!100", "!", sourceCols(i + 2))).Value
        
        'Loop through the current "check" column
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(dataCheck, 1)
            If dataCheck(j, 1) <> vbNullString Then
                'If value is not empty, insert the respective value into the output array
                outputIndex = outputIndex + 1
                
                dataOutput(1, outputIndex) = dataCheck(j, 1)
                dataOutput(2, outputIndex) = dataFirstCol(j, 1)
                dataOutput(3, outputIndex) = dataSecondCol(j, 1)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    'Resize the output array
    ReDim Preserve dataOutput(1 To 3, 1 To outputIndex) As Variant
                        
    '====== Start to insert value in BOM ======
    Dim TargetSht As Worksheet
    Set TargetSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BOM")
    
    ' What row do I start the paste on
    Const startRow As Long = 9
    
    ' Clear the previous BOM items before creating/refreshing
    TargetSht.Rows(startRow & ":" & TargetSht.Rows.Count).ClearContents
    TargetSht.Cells(startRow, 1).Resize(UBound(dataOutput, 2), UBound(dataOutput, 1)).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dataOutput)
End Sub
```

I assume that you only intend to read through row 9 - 100 in both tables from your source sheet so the upper limit of the output array is fixed at 200 and resize again later.

Comment: thanks mate, that is much cleaner and does indeed work. Thanks for the clear explanations as well!